# Creating a new App on a company page

Tags: facebook

We are developing an iPhone app for a company which uses facebook connect.  When adding the app to FB we normally login to the company's account at developer.facebook.com and set up the app of that account.

In this case, an employee at the company has set up a facebook page for the company, but uses his personal account.  He made me an admin for the facebook page, but I don't see a place to add the APP.  Of course I can add the app on our company's account or this employee's account, but if we do, when the our iphone app is set up using FB connect the personal account will show up as the developer account.

How do I associate the facebook connect app with the company's page?  Do they need to create a new FB account for this app or for the company?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

To connect your Facebook application with your Facebook page, you will need to create a custom tab and to access your Facebook Developers account where you set up the Facebook app. The custom tab settings let you add the application as a tab to any Facebook page, including your own pages.

1. Go to [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) and click the "Apps" option on the top menu bar. You may be prompted to sign in to your Facebook account if you're not already logged in.
2. Go to the left sidebar and click the application title you want to edit. Click the "Edit" link near the upper-right side of the "Settings" bar.
3. Click the "On Facebook" link from the left sidebar. Copy the website address from the "Canvas URL" in the "Canvas" section to the "Tab URL" field of the "Page Tabs" section. Next, copy the "Secure Canvas URL" field from the "Canvas" section to the "Secure Tab URL" field in the "Page Tabs" area. Click the "Save Changes" button.
4. Go to Facebook.com and type the name of your app in the top search box. Select the "See More Results" link from the drop-down list.
5. Go to the left column of the application's About page and click the "Add to Page" link. On the pop-up screen, click the "Add to Page" button next to the Facebook page you want it added to. Click the "Close" button.
6. Visit your Facebook page and you will see a new tab on the left sidebar below the profile picture. The tab should have the title of your app. If you click on the tab, it will load your application on the Facebook page.